# Moq setting method return value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the below class, and I am trying to test the method AddRecordToQueue.

I am using Moq to mock the result of the the AddToQueue method within the AddRecordToQueue method.

The AddToQueue method returns a boolean, so i am trying to mock the result with a true value

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly IRabbitMqConnection rabbitMqConnection;

    public Test(IRabbitMqConnection rabbitMqConnection)
    {
        this.rabbitMqConnection = rabbitMqConnection;

    }

    public bool AddRecordToQueue(string messageExchange, object data)
    {
        var jsonified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var customerBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonified);
        var result = this.rabbitMqConnection.AddToQueue(customerBuffer, messageExchange);
        return result;
    }
}
```

My test class looks like the below.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestCon
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MockTest()
    {
        Moq.Mock<IRabbitMqConnection> rabbitConection = new Moq.Mock<IRabbitMqConnection>();

        var draftContactsManager = new Test(rabbitConection.Object);

        rabbitConection.Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(null, string.Empty)).Returns((bool res) => true);

        var result = draftContactsManager.AddRecordToQueue("someExchange", null);

        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}
```

I cant seem to set the moq result as true. Can anyone advise what I am missing

thanks

Comment: Not at a machine to test, but there are two things I see here. 1. You should `Setup` before you get a reference to the `.Object`; 2. In `Setup`, you set the arguments to null, and empty, try using `Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(It.IsAny(), Is.IsAny())).Returns(true))`

Comment: Actually you do't have to do Setup before getting the Object

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think that you need to change the `Returns` to just return true instead of the lambda. Like this:

```
rabbitConection.Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(null, string.Empty)).Returns(true)
```

EDIT:

If this still doesn't work then it is probably due to the parameters not matching. You are passing in `"someExchange"` but the mock is set up for string.Empty. If you aren't sure what values will be used you could use the `It.IsAny` method to get around this.

```
rabbitConection.Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true)
```

Comment: Make sure in your setup you are using It.IsAny for all parameters and not some test variable that you arranged.

Answer (score 6):

You need to setup the method with the actual arguments it's invoked.
If `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)` returns null, then this is the setup:

```
rabbitConection.Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(null, "someExchange")).Returns(true)
```

Additionally, you can setup the method to return true/false regardless of values of the arguments:

```
rabbitConection.Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true)
```

With the above setup, the method will return `true` no matter what what you've passed to the method. The previous example will return true only when the method is called with the setuped arguments.

Answer (score 2):

1. As the others said, the Setup is incorrect.
2. You need to call `Setup` **before** using the associated `Object`

It should be something similar to:

```
...
rabbitConection
    .Setup(e => e.AddToQueue(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(true);
var draftContactsManager = new Test(rabbitConection.Object);
...
```

Comment: This is not true. The .Setup arguments just did not match, but the reference to .Object can be used before (e.g. in a fixture setup).

Comment: Why this answer has +1 vote if it is completely wrong?