# How to mock a method and return a result that's set by its callback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, moq

I'm using the code below to mock a `UserManager`.

The problem I'm having is that `oResult` remains null. But I'm unable to give it a value outside of the callback, as a password is only available inside the callback. I can't just return a predetermined value (e.g. `IdentityResult.Success`), as the result must be generated at runtime.

These three questions are similar, but they don't exactly cover the issue:

1. [validate MOQ unit test method return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38738511) (this is the closest)
2. [mocking a method using Moq framework doesn't return expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50963331)
3. [Moq setting method return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32633184)

The difference between all of these and my situation is that in mine the method's required input value is only available within the callback.

I'm using this to test the behaviors of my controller(s).

How can I execute a callback for a mocked method (`CreateAsync()` in this case) and return its result?

---

```vb
Protected Function UserManagerMock(Of TUser As Db.User, TCity as Db.City)(Users As List(Of TUser)) As Mock(Of UserManager)
  Dim oManagerMock As Mock(Of UserManager)
  Dim oStoreMock As Mock(Of IUserStore(Of TUser))
  Dim oCallback As Action(Of TUser, String)
  Dim oManager As UserManager
  Dim oResult As IdentityResult
  Dim oSetup As Expression(Of Func(Of UserManager, Task(Of IdentityResult)))

  oStoreMock = New Mock(Of IUserStore(Of TUser))
  oManagerMock = New Mock(Of UserManager)(oUserStoreMock.Object)
  oManager = oUserManagerMock.Object
  oCallback = Sub(User, Password, City)
                oResult = oManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(Password).Result

                If oResult Is IdentityResult.Success Then
                  User.PasswordHash = oManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Password)
                  Users.Add(User)
                End If
              End Sub

  oManager.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator
  oManager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of TUser)(oManager)

  oSetup = Function(Manager) Manager.CreateAsync(It.IsAny(Of Db.User), It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of Db.City))
  oUserManagerMock.Setup(oSetup).ReturnsAsync(oResult).Callback(oCallback)

  Return oManagerMock
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by doing away with the callback altogether, and instead using a

```vb
Func(Of ..., Task(Of IdentityResult))
```

in the setup's `Returns()` call.

Example:

```vb
Protected Function GetUserManager(Users As List(Of Db.User)) As UserManager
  Return Me.GetUserManagerMock(Of Db.User, Db.City)(Users).Object
End Function

Private Function GetUserManagerMock(Of TUser As Db.User, TCity As Db.City)(Users As List(Of TUser)) As Mock(Of UserManager)
  Dim oManagerMock As Mock(Of UserManager)
  Dim oStoreMock As Mock(Of IUserStore(Of TUser))
  Dim oManager As UserManager
  Dim oReturn As Func(Of TUser, String, TCity, Task(Of IdentityResult))
  Dim oResult As IdentityResult
  Dim oSetup As Expression(Of Func(Of UserManager, Task(Of IdentityResult)))

  oStoreMock = New Mock(Of IUserStore(Of TUser))
  oManagerMock = New Mock(Of UserManager)(oUserStoreMock.Object)
  oManager = oUserManagerMock.Object

  oReturn = Async Function(User, Password, City)
              If City.IsNothing Then
                oResult = IdentityResult.Failed($"{NameOf(City)} is required.")
              Else
                oResult = Await oManager.UserValidator.ValidateAsync(User)

                If oResult Is IdentityResult.Success Then
                  oResult = Await oManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(Password)

                  If oResult Is IdentityResult.Success Then
                    User.PasswordHash = oManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Password)
                    Users.Add(User)

                    User.CityId = City.Id
                    User.City = City

                    City.Users.Add(User)
                  End If
                End If
              End If

              Return oResult
            End Function

  oSetup = Function(Manager) Manager.CreateAsync(It.IsAny(Of Db.User), It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of Db.City))
  oManagerMock.Setup(oSetup).Returns(oReturn)

  Return oManagerMock
End Function
```

Use it like this:

```vb
<Fact>
Public Async Function CreateUser() As Task
  Dim oUserManager As UserManager
  Dim oResult As IdentityResult
  Dim sPassword As String
  Dim oUser as Db.User
  Dim oCity as Db.City
  
  sPassword = "P@ssw0rd!"
  oUser = New Db.User With {.FirstName = "User", .LastName = "Name", .UserName = "user.name", .Email = "username@domain.com"}
  oCity = New Db.City With {.Id = 1, .Name = "BigCity", .Code = "L69CNV5"}

  oUserManager = Me.GetUserManager(Me.Users)
  oResult = Await oUserManager.CreateAsync(oUser, sPassword, oCity)

  Assert.True(oResult.Succeeded)
End Function
```

Source [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/1069#issuecomment-707332063). Thanks again to [`stakx`](https://github.com/stakx).